# An approximate solution of a second-order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, special-functions, approximation, quantum-mechanics

In the book, *Mathematical Methods for Students of Physics and Related Fields, Second Edition* by Sadri Hassani, Page 667, the author has stated that, for the following differential equation

$y''(x) - x^2 y(x) \approx 0$,

where $x \to \infty$, one can *easily* obtain an approximate solution of the form $e^{\pm x^2/2}$.

Is there any approach to obtain this solution, *besides* solving the exact differential equation $y''(x) - x^2 y(x) = 0$ by the Frobenius method, and then taking the limit of the solutions (Hermite polynomials) as $x \to \infty$?

Comment: An idea for how to think about a heuristic approach: $(D+x)(D-x)=D^2-Dx+xD-x^2$, so in reverse $D^2-x^2=(D+x)(D-x)+Dx-xD$. Now $Dx-xD=1$ (the identity operator), so your equation is $((D+x)(D-x)+1)y=0$. Can you argue that the $1$ term is "just a perturbation" for large $x$? If so, then the "leading order" problem is much easier since it can be solved by the method of integrating factors.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for your insightful comment.

Comment: Is Frobenius method that one presume the solution of the second order diff equ can be expanded to infinite series and so try to get the solution this way?

Comment: @CharlieChang Exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the equation $y''-qy=0$ with $0<q(x)\to\infty$ for $x\to\infty$ has the WKB approximation (see wikipedia, this is a standard example) of basis solutions
$$
y(x)=q(x)^{-\frac14}\exp\left(\pm\int\sqrt{q(x)}dx\right)
$$
where the first factor is the second order term in the expansion. So indeed, in first order you would get $y(x)=\exp(\pm\frac{x^2}2)$, while in second order, there would be additionally a factor $\frac1{\sqrt{x}}$.

---

The approach is to set $y=\exp(S)$ with an expansion $S=S_0+S_1+S_2+...$ where $S_0\gg S_1\gg S_2\gg...$ for $x\to\infty$. This scale also translates to the derivatives. Set for shortness $S'=s$ then isolating the components of equal scale in $s'+s^2-q=0$ gives
$$
s_0^2=q\\
s_0'+2s_0s_1=0\\\vdots
$$
which implies $s_0=\pm\sqrt q$ and $s_1=-\frac{s_0'}{2s_0}\implies S_1=-\frac12\ln|s_0|=-\frac14\ln(q)$.

Comment: Thanks for writing an answer. If we want to check the solutions, i.e., $e^{\pm x^2/2}$, and insert them in the differential equation: $y''(x) - x^2 y(x) \approx 0$; for the negative-sign solution, we get: $- e^{-x^2/2} \approx 0$ where as $x$ goes to infinity, the exponential vanishes, so it's a correct solution. My question is: Why is the positive-sign solution also acceptable? (Because it doesn't satisfy the differential equation.)

Comment: The remainder $e^{x^2/2}$ is small against the other terms of size $x^2e^{x^2/2}$ for $x\approx\infty$. This is not much, but it is also only the first asymptotic approximation.

Comment: @Novice In fact in terms of relative error the situation winds up being the same: the relative error decays as a negative power of $x$ as $|x| \to \infty$. This is loosely speaking because the "exponential character" of the solution is already correctly captured by the leading order WKB approximation.